# 「信頼されていないエンタープライズ開発元」と表示され、アプリが起動できない

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

iOS9.0 開発バージョン(iPhone6)
AppleWatch バージョン 1.0.1 開発バージョン
XCode 7.0 Beta
という環境でAppleWatchのアプリをEnterprise programで作成しました。作成したといってもサンプルアプリをビルドしただけですが。

ビルド及びインストールは成功しました。
しかし、アプリを起動しようとアイコンをタップしたら

> **信頼されていないエンタープライズ開発元**
>
> "iPhone Distribution: xxx Corp."はこのiPhoneでは信頼されていません。この開発元が信頼されるまで、そのエンタープライズAppは使用できません。
>
> [了解]

とのポップアップメッセージで起動ができません。
[設定]メニューからも設定箇所が見つかりませんし、Enterpriseでよくあるように信頼する/信頼しないという確認ポップアップも出てきませんでした。

何かお心あたりある方は、ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 本家に同じ質問がありましたので、こちら貼っておきます。

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722883/ios9-untrusted-enterprise-developer-with-no-option-to-trust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/known-issues-with-ios

日本語でも説明書いてみました
http://nariya-takemura.blogspot.jp/2015/06/ios90.html

設定 -> プロファイル -> 信頼